# How to use lapply instead of the for loop?

Tags: r

I am attempting to calculate the number of hours in a time interval that is considered to be in the evening (here calculated from 16:00). Below is an example.

```
                start                 end  evening
1 2018-01-01 10:47:05 2018-01-01 16:36:03 0.600924
2 2018-01-02 04:05:56 2018-01-02 14:24:59 0.000000
3 2018-01-02 13:37:41 2018-01-03 00:47:31 5.000000
4 2018-01-02 22:53:31 2018-01-03 04:43:59 0.000000
5 2018-01-03 17:04:20 2018-01-03 22:27:39 3.927569
```

I made a function, `f_overlap()`, that calculates the number of evening hours on each row. Running it in a `for` loop would look like this:

```
library(lubridate)

...

for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$evening[row] <- f_overlap(eveningStart,
                               eveningEnd,
                               interval(df[row,'start'], df[row,'end']))
}
```

I can't get my head around using `lapply()` instead of the `for` loop, and the tutorials I've read out there and the questions I've read at SO hasn't been to any help so far. So, can someone help me out here, showing me how you would achieve the same results with `lapply()`?

Comment: `lapply` is probably the wrong tool here. If you really don't want to use your `for` loop, probably `mapply` would make more sense, although we would need more details on `f_overlap` in order to see how best to use it with `mapply`.

Comment: As @joran said, you likely need `mapply` instead. However, if your goal is to speed up things, know that a `*apply` won't make any difference, with respect to a `for` loop. Rather, you should try to vectorize `f_overlap`, so you can get rid of both loops and `*apply`.

Comment: @Christian Have you seen my answer? Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

A `sapply()` should fit well.

```
evening <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), f_overlap)
> cbind(df1, evening=evening)
                start                 end   evening
1 2018-01-01 10:47:05 2018-01-01 16:36:03 0.6008333
2 2018-01-02 04:05:56 2018-01-02 14:24:59 0.0000000
3 2018-01-02 13:37:41 2018-01-03 00:47:31 5.0000000
4 2018-01-02 22:53:31 2018-01-03 04:43:59 0.0000000
5 2018-01-03 17:04:20 2018-01-03 22:27:39 3.9277778
```

If you rely on `lapply()` you'll have to `unlist()` or `rbind()` the output:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df1), f_overlap))  # rbind, or
unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df1), f_overlap))  # unlist
```

You can use both alternatives also with the `cbind()` above.

I've tried to reconstruct what your `f_overlap()` function does, the values are at least very similar.

```
f_overlap <- function(x) {
  i0 <- as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(as.Date(df1[x,]$start)), "16:00"))
  t0 <- df1[x, ]$start
  t1 <- df1[x, ]$end
  i1 <- as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(as.Date(df1[x,]$start)), "21:00"))
  if (t0 < i0 & t1 < i0) return(0)
  else if (t0 < i0 & t1 > i1) return(5)
  else if (t0 > i1 & t1 > i1) return (0)
  else if (t0 > i0 & t1 < i1) 
    return(difftime(t1, t0, units="hours"))
  else if (t0 < i0 & t1 < i1) 
    return(difftime(t1, i0, units="hours"))
  else if (t0 > i0 & t1 > i1) 
    return(difftime(i1, t0, units="hours"))
}
```